# Trouble configuring App Engine task queue

Tags: google-app-engine, task-queue

I defined a task queue in queue.yaml as follows:

```
- name: queue-name
  mode: push
  max_concurrent_requests: 10
  rate: 10/h
  retry_parameters:
    min_backoff_seconds: 5
    max_backoff_seconds: 120
    task_retry_limit: 10
    task_age_limit: 1d
```

When I look at it in the developers console after deployment, I see an error that says:

```
This queue has been disabled, and removed from queue.yaml / queue.xml
```

I'm not exactly sure what the issue is. If I change the rate to 10/s, the errors goes away. Any ideas?

Comment: I've tried to change the rate to 0.0028/s which is roughly the equivalent of 10/h and still see the problem. There must be something fundamental that I'm forgetting.

Comment: Something else to note: the old App Engine UI doesn't show any issues with the queue, but the new UI does. Maybe it's a display issue with the new UI?

Comment: I see such message for one of my queues in new UI, but in fact -- its working just fine. And no message in the old UI.

Comment: I also see the same error. Only on the new UI, on the old UI it's good. It happens only if the rate is slower than 1/s

Answer (score 0):

This is now a known issue and has been brought to the attention of the engineering team. The issues appears to be only with the Developers Console UI. The queue should still function as configured.

You can keep track of the issue on the ['Google App Engine' public issue track](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12282&q=task%20queue%20component%3DTaskQueue&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log)